# Boggle: What is the dice configuration for Boggle in various languages?

Tags: boggle

This is the dice configuration for the English Boggle:

[image: English 16 dice version]

Other variants and discussions concerning letter distributions for English can be found here:

- [The Boggle cube redesign and its effect on the difficulty of Boggle](http://www.bananagrammer.com/2013/10/the-boggle-cube-redesign-and-its-effect.html),
- [Boggle - Everything2.com](http://everything2.com/title/Boggle),
- [Letter Distribution | BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/300883/letter-distribution),
- [Talk:Boggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3aBoggle) (Wikipedia).

I am interested in the **16 dice** configurations for also other languages (Spanish in particular) and I am unable to find it anywhere online.

---

Versions I have managed to find so far:

- [**Czech** 16 dice version](http://www.deskovehry.info/pravidla/boggle.htm),
- **English** 25 dice version:
   [image: English 25 dice]
- **Spanish** 25 dice version:
   [image: Spanish 25 dice]
- **Italian** 25 dice version:
   [image: Italian 25 dice]

Answer (score 4):

[This French page](http://www.courbis.fr/Boggle-quelques-statistiques.html) gives the following configuration for a 16 die Boggle version:

`ETUKNO EVGTIN DECAMP IELRUW`
`EHIFSE RECALS ENTDOS OFXRIA`
`NAVEDZ EIOATA GLENYU BMAQJO`
`TLIBRA SPULTE AIMSOR ENHRIS`

According to [this French wikipedia article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boggle) it is the configuration for the 'international' edition of Boggle.

I assume it is also the configuration for the Portugese 16-die version, since it is used for a Portugese Excel version of Boggle (see [here](http://br.ccm.net/faq/12814-o-jogo-no-excel-vba-le-boggle)).

Comment: I found another web site that state the same dice. It has a solution finder: https://www.dcode.fr/solveur-boggle-4x4

Answer (score 3):

The (one of?) the German version(s) you can find on my blog at http://blogabissl.blogspot.com/2016/08/boggle.html, standard 4 times 4 = 16 dice, including the way I turned the dice.

Answer (score 3):

I finally got my hands on a Spanish version of a 4x4 (16 dice) Boggle, specifically the "enclosed electronic-timer" version (sometimes referred to as "Scrabble Boggle" or "Boggle Reinvention")

The dice configuration is:

`ARHSDE FUAARB IOTALG UOEEOCh*`
`FOMTUI OODBLG RPSZTL EBIOUA`
`CAREME RSJEFI NSXJAH UVDQBCh*`
`NBIMEE BAANIT EPVOCU SCAAPT`

*In Spanish Boggle, Ch is printed together but counts as two separate letters when scoring.

Answer (score 3):

Another 16-die Spanish version from Argentinean manufacturer Kipo's:

```
['N', 'D', 'S', 'E', 'A', 'O'], ['A', 'O', 'U', 'E', 'A', 'I'],
['N', 'I', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'U'], ['V', 'O', 'N', 'J', 'S', 'L'],
['E', 'S', 'O', 'Ñ', 'A', 'D'], ['E', 'Qu', 'O', 'S', 'H', 'D'],
['C', 'E', 'N', 'O', 'L', 'S'], ['D', 'T', 'A', 'R', 'O', 'I'],
['C', 'N', 'I', 'R', 'T', 'F'], ['P', 'S', 'C', 'E', 'L', 'O'],
['E', 'H', 'I', 'X', 'U', 'R'], ['B', 'O', 'M', 'L', 'E', 'Z'],
['A', 'R', 'E', 'C', 'M', 'A'], ['S', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'N', 'O'],
['P', 'O', 'D', 'E', 'T', 'A'], ['B', 'R', 'A', 'E', 'L', 'A']
```

(my apologies if the brackets and commas are uncomfortable, I'm taking this from my JavaScript project)

Answer (score 3):

I made Dice combination in Bosnian language.
It can be used in Serb and Croat language.
Dice configuration:
[image: Configuration]

Answer (score 2):

We've been playing Super Boggle (by Parker) many times every day for the last 20 years. The letters on the cubes have started to become illegible. You can no longer buy Super Boggle (5x5 with flashing 3-minute timer), as I think it was lost when Hasbro took over from Parker.

It's the best version of the game, so I just needed to replace the letter cubes.

I suspect that other "English" versions on this site are actually "American English". We have been playing "British English" and so the letter distribution in the cubes is different. See letter distribution list below.

**SOLUTION:** I found that by buying 2 of the Hasbro 4x4 versions of British Boggle (Hasbro C2187 Boggle Classic from Amazon), all 16 of the cubes from the 1st set were the same as my original 25 cubes, and then I could use 9 of the cubes from the 2nd set to complete the duplicates which were in the original. Ths is shown below.

I'm happy again. We have a full 5x5 Super Boggle set again. Modern Big Boggle is not the same.

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify: Which format is the list for? You mention 4 different games/letter sets in your answer, and two in the paragraph you reference the list (american english and british english)

Answer (score 2):

Italian 16 and Finnish dice configuration.

A-A-E-I-O-T  A-B-O-O-M-Qu  A-B-I-L-R-T  A-C-E-L-R-S
A-C-D-E-M-P  A-C-F-I-O-R  A-D-E-N-V-Z  A-I-M-O-R-S
C-E-N-O-T-U  D-E-N-O-S-T  E-E-F-H-I-S  E-G-L-N-O-U
E-G-I-N-T-V  E-H-I-N-R-S  E-I-L-O-R-U  E-L-P-S-T-U

A-N-FG-Ä-T-O  Ä-A-N-I-T-I  A-K-BC-L-Ä-E  A-Ä-O-A-A-A
E-A-K-H-L-N  I-A-L-J-O-K  E-Y-U-T-V-H  S-S-K-E-M-P
N-T-U-R-S-P  E-K-S-T-L-M  E-I-E-I-N-D  T-O-I-A-Ä-N
N-I-Ö-T-E-J  S-I-O-R-M-N  I-S-T-L-U-N  V-U-S-S-T-Y

Answer (score 0):

**Warning, the chart in answer by Mac 9/15/2020 has error.**

[image: corrected]

As last edited Sep 15 '20, the chart has an error.
The faces of die 11 should be EEINSU (U is correct, V is wrong).

I can verify that all other die in the chart are correct per the physical
Parker Brothers 4x4 game 00384 (number on box) aka 0384C-1 (number
on printed instruction sheet that is copyright 1973, 1997 by Hasbro, Inc.)
which I believe is for US English, aka American English.

The 00384 game die are 18mm wide.  Inexpensive blank spares (eg):
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32970377768.html