# Boggle - Letter distribution and face orientation of each die

Tags: boggle

I am making my own set of Boggle dice (standard 16 cube).  How is the letter distribution set on each face of each die (all oriented the same way and facing you using the standard Boggle letter distribution, below) what letters are on the top face, bottom, right, left, front and back?  The following chart is from Everything2.com

The 16 dice have the following 96 letters on their faces:

```
 1. A E A N E G      9. W N G E E H
 2. A H S P C O     10. L N H N R Z
 3. A S P F F K     11. T S T I Y D
 4. O B J O A B     12. O W T O A T
 5. I O T M U C     13. E R T T Y L
 6. R Y V D E L     14. T O E S S I
 7. L R E I X D     15. T E R W H V
 8. E I U N E S     16. N U I H M Qu
```

So, for die #1 if the A is on top where are the other letters in relation to the A?

Comment: Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29264/boggle-what-is-the-dice-configuration-for-boggle-in-various-languages?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'll find that the answer doesn't matter for your specific case:

If we assume every die is a fair die (which means every face has exactly 1/6 chance of coming face up, and is what you should strive for when building the cubes for your version of the game), the position of the letters in each die will not matter, since every face will have the same chance of showing up in your grid, and each die can only ever show a single face.

Therefore, all that matters is the distribution of these letters, which will ultimately affect how many instances of a letter you'll see in your board; and you seem to have found a pretty solid distribution for the standard English language scrabble.