# Does anyone know the letters used in Swedish Boggle?

Tags: boggle

Similar to this question, but specifically for the Swedish version
[Boggle: What is the dice configuration for Boggle in various languages?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29264/boggle-what-is-the-dice-configuration-for-boggle-in-various-languages?rq=1)
(https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameversion/228158/parker-swedish-finnish-edition-1994)

I would like to know which letters each of the 16 dice have. Also any extra information on how the game works with the Swedish vowels å, ä, ö. I know with the German version you use extra letters to make up for the missing umlauts e.g. ä --> ae, is it similar to this?